# React: How to clear TextArea?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, components

I know how to control input component. But this behaviour I didn't understand at all. 
I have antd form with textarea in it.

```
<Item
  name='tags'
  className='input-item tag-helper'
  label='These are tags that appear on your NFT'
>
  <TextArea value={text} className='big-text-area tag-text-area' placeholder='Enter a tag...' onKeyDown={addTag} />
</Item>
```

The textArea responsible for adding tags. So when I write something in input It controls by useState variable and after space press, It's added to an array with tags. After space press, input has to clear but nothing happens. 
My code looks like this right now:

```
  const addTag = value => {
    setText(value.target.value)
    if (value.keyCode === 32) {
      setTags([...tags, text])
      setText('')
    }
  }
```

In earlier version:

```
const addTag = value => {
  if (value.keyCode === 32) {
    setTags([...tags, text])
    setText('')
  }
}

<Item
  name='tags'
  className='input-item tag-helper'
  label='These are tags that appear on your NFT'
>
  <TextArea value={text} className='big-text-area tag-text-area' placeholder='Enter a tag...' onKeyDown={addTag} onChange={v => setText(v.target.value)} />
</Item>
```

Also, I thought that It a good idea to try setting text through `useEffect`, so I experimented and added the last one func:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setText('')
}, [tags])
```

Can somebody say me what I'm doing wrong? Why I can't clear textArea after I press "space"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the task. I can't control the component because it's was wrapped in `Form.Item`, Item's has they own state, so It disturb to control `Input` directly.
Here is the changes:

```
<TextArea value={text} onChange={v => setText(v.target.value)} onKeyUp={addTag} className='big-text-area tag-text-area' placeholder='Enter a tag...' />

const addTag = value => {
  if (value.keyCode === 32) {
    setTags([...tags, text])
    setText('')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be something regarding the fact that you are not passing an `onChange` prop to `TextArea` so it is not in controlled mode and it is ignoring the `value` prop you are passing to it. You could try this:

```
<TextArea value={text} onChange={() => {}} className='big-text-area tag-text-area' placeholder='Enter a tag...' onKeyDown={addTag} />
```

or you can do this in the `onChange`

```
const onChange = (e) => {
  const currentText = e.target.value;
  if(currentText.length && currentText[currentText.length - 1] === " "){
    setTags([...tags, text]);
    setText("");
  } else {
    setText(e.target.value);
  }
}
```

and leave the `TextArea` like this

```
<TextArea value={text} onChange={onChange} className='big-text-area tag-text-area' placeholder='Enter a tag...' />
```

Comment: I write code "like in tutorial" (see an earlier version of my code). But the main trouble is `setText()` in `onChange`, It calls after `onKeyDown`, so my variable rewrites with the old value.

Comment: Have you tried with an empty `onChange` like I write in the answer?

Comment: I tried both variants.

Comment: I edited the answer, have you tried that?

Comment: I tried both of them.

Answer (score 0):

Adding event.persist(); worked for me for clearing the textarea, with regards to tags list it depends entirely depends on what your initial state is and how you are managing with tags array.

```
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);

  const addTag = event => {
      event.persist();
      console.log(tags);
      setText(event.value);
      if (event.keyCode === 32) { 
          setText('');   
          setTags((previousTags) => {
             return [...previousTags,event.target.value];
          });        
      }
  };

 // textarea are I used 
<textarea value={text} className='big-text-area tag-text-area' placeholder='Enter a tag...' onChange={addTag} onKeyDown={addTag} />
```

Comment: Unfortunately, It's not working to me because It's add a last symbol to array (and this symbol is "space").

Comment: Hi, it is good to see you have resolved the problem now, I have also updated the answer, it now updates the list immediately as you press the space and also provide the correct values.